# Esta el español en su periodo Posclasico, le sucedara al español lo mismo que al latin?

Tags: historia

Observando la historia de las lenguas, en particular el latin, todas estas pasan por un periodo de nacimiento, madurez, prolificacion y muerte.

El latin apareció cerca del siglo VIII AC y Su diversificación y posterior muerte se inició alrededor del siglo X; esto son 18 siglos de vida.

El español se inició en su periodo clásico como castellano en el siglo IX, dándole hasta la actualidad unos 12 siglos de vida .

Ahora, cabe indicar que la aparición del castellano no fue una evolución del latín, si no una distorsión, pues el latín castellano no fue un latín del todo asimilado por los ibéricos formando su propia variante del latín.

Si analizamos las similitudes del español de las Américas con el del latín junto a las épocas doradas de Roma y España, podemos identificar un patrón el cual es: la prolificacion del lenguaje, el periodo posclasico y la muerte.

La única diferencia es que en esta ocasión no ha existido ninguna Guerra que venga a imponer un Nuevo idioma dándole autonomía a cada región.

Sin embargo, los países actuales son completamente autónomos y esto ha diversificado el uso del lenguaje dándonos dos grandes ramas: el español castellano y el español latino, eso sin contar todas las variedades del español hablado en España, como el catalán, gallego, aranés, aragonés, entre otros.

Esto me trae muchas otras preguntas como: es el lenguaje parte de la identidad de una comunidad o es la comunidad lo que le da la identidad al lenguaje?

Comment: Me he permitido con tu permiso editar un poco tu pregunta para arreglar un poco el efecto del autocorrector, mayúsculas o tildes. También dos faltas: distorSión y ocaSión. Como yo pronuncio C y S muy diferentes es un error muy llamativo. Finalmente, quedaría que el uso de los gerundios para acción posterior al verbo es incorrecto, pero bueno, eso ya sería hilar fino jaja.

Comment: Gracias, tengo la mala suerte de estar en una computadora en ingles, y mi dependencia tecnologica por el auto-corrector se vuelve cada vez mas evidente.(asi como tambien sufro de que esto me autocorrige al ingles)

en cuanto al uso de la C y S, supongo que es uno rasgo del español latino que ha sufrido la homologacion de la pronunciacion de ambas letras, seguramente no tendriamos tanta dificultad en diferenciarlas si no hubieramos perdido dicha pronunicacion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bueno, primero permíteme un comentario:  catalán, gallego, aranés o aragonés son **idiomas diferentes**; no son en ningún caso "variedades de español".

Dicho esto, y para responder a lo demás... bueno, no tenemos una bola de cristal para ver el futuro y nadie puede prever lo que sucederá. Quizás la civilización finalice antes de que se extinga el castellano; quizá la colonización lingüística acelere demasiado... no lo sabemos.

Pero eso sí, debes tener en cuenta una serie de diferencias, entre las que destacan **la imprenta e Internet**. Es evidente que la evolución del español fue mucho más rápida cuando no había imprenta. Cuando se difunden textos escritos, el cambio es más lento. También lo fue desde los inicios de la RAE en el s. XVIII, aunque ésta sí recoge cambios (algunos de los cuales no me gustan jeje), pero al ritmo actual de evolución del idioma casi se puede considerar lenta. Y luego está Internet y su contradicción. Por un lado las redes sociales aceleran la evolución, pero por otro lado nunca antes había existido tal difusión de textos escritos, e incluso se están recuperando formas arcaicas.

Personalmente, yo más bien observo lo contrario. Observo un gran interés internacional por los idiomas y el español está afortunadamente en una posición privilegiada. Sigo pensando que pese a factores políticos el español continúa siendo un idioma muy solicitado, así que sería extraño que se extinguiera.

Comment: me gusta tu respuesta, 
con esta logica hemos visto como las reglas y el uso es mas facil de extender y mas facil entender nuestras diferencias para lograr una comunicacion mas eficiente logrando obtener una evolucion paralela en lugar de una accidentada por las barreras de comunicacion que enfrentabamos en el pasado